# I am trying to render a random array element from a button click using axios and a local json file. What am I missing?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I have got it now where I can render the entire array in a random order, just cant render one element of the array. I am also having an issue in showing the entire json object instead of just the text of the quote.

here is the html:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button v-on:click="getTeacupData">Get Teacup Data</button>
    <!-- <div>{{ teacupDataList }}</div> -->
    <div
      v-for="teacupData in teacupDataList"
      :key="teacupData.quote"
      class="teacup-data"
    >
      <div>
        <span class="quote">
          {{
            teacupDataList[Math.floor(Math.random() * teacupData.quote.length)]
          }}</span
        >
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

and here is the script:

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  name: 'Teacup',
  data() {
    return {
      teacupDataList: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getTeacupData() {
      axios.get('/teacupProph.json').then((response) => {
        this.teacupDataList = response.data
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a computed property called `randomQuote` as follows :

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  name: 'Teacup',
  data() {
    return {
      teacupDataList: []
    }
  },
 computed:{
  randomQuote(){
  const rand=Math.floor(Math.random() * this.teacupDataList.length)
     return this.teacupDataList[rand]?this.teacupDataList[rand].quote:""
   }
  },
  methods: {
    getTeacupData() {
      axios.get('/teacupProph.json').then((response) => {
        this.teacupDataList = response.data
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

in template don't use `v-for` loop just call the computed property :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button v-on:click="getTeacupData">Get Teacup Data</button>
    <!-- <div>{{ teacupDataList }}</div> -->

      <div>
        <span class="quote">
          {{
            randomQuote
          }}</span>
      </div>

  </div>
</template>
```

**Edit**

place your json file inside the components folder and call it like `axios('./teacupProph.json')` and fix the `@:click` to `@click`, check this [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-minsky-rpuxg)

Comment: I am getting teacupData and teacupDataList is not defined

Comment: use this before them like `this.teacupDataList` check my edited answer

Comment: I am now getting.... this error Cannot read property 'quote' of undefined

Comment: the json object is set up like this: 

[
  {
    "quote": Hot dogs are great",
    "id": "1"
  },
  {
    "quote": "If you were a hot dog, would you eat yourself?",
    "id": "2"
 
  }
]

Comment: this should work if we set `let rand=Math.floor(Math.random() * this.teacupData.quote.length)
     return this.teacupDataList[rand]?this.teacupDataList[rand].quote:""`

Comment: `computed: {
    randomQuote() {
      const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.teacupData.quote.length)
      return this.teacupDataList[rand] ? this.teacupDataList[rand].quote : ''
    }
  }`  
still getting quote undefined

Comment: you should do `let rand=Math.floor(Math.random() * this.teacupDataList.length)`?

Comment: the undefined comes from `this.teacupData.quote.length`

Comment: ok now there is no undefined error but nothing is rendered when the button is clicked

Comment: the provided code doesn't match  the code in your question

Comment: yes it does it is set in a component that is called in the App.js

Comment: i think you missed to save

Comment: the json file doesn't exist

Comment: please add the teacupProph.json file

Comment: I did it is in the public folder.

Comment: that did it. Thanks so much! you rock!